# How to access variable in a different file

Tags: python

In my sanic async project, I have a main file called app.py in which I have defined the app instance as such:

```
from sanic import Sanic
app=Sanic(name='myapp')
```

Now, I have a different file utility.py in which I want to access the config details for which I will need this app instance. So, how to **make the app instance globally available**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with asyncio.  It's just basic Python.  When the interpreter reaches the line in app.py:

```
app=Sanic(name='myapp')
```

it instantiates an instance of Sanic and assigns to a variable named "app" that is global to the module app.py.

In utilities.py you put a line something like this:

```
from app import app
```

This imports the variable named "app" from the module app.py.  You may have to modify `from ___ import app` to reflect how you have laid out your modules and packages. But that's the general idea.

For this to work, your top-level script must import app before it imports utilities.